# how to filter the blank spaces only sent contact form 7 wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, textarea, message

I am using the contact form 7 ,I want to know how to filter the blank spaces sent from the text area.
Is there any plug in that could filter the white spaces only, that is being sent from text area?
If no,how could I edit the codes on contact form 7 to costumize the text area?what folder and what php file must be tweak?
I nead help please.
-thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @j_s_stack thanks for the concern I already edited the title..I hope you could help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please add this function in your theme functions.php file.

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else");

function wpcf7_do_something_else(&$wpcf7_data) {

 $wpcf7_data['text_area_field_name'] =   trim($wpcf7_data['text_area_field_name'] );
}
```

This hook can be used to filter the form data before sending email.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I found it wrong, I tried to copy your codes but doesnt work,I bet, I know the algorithm for it,but I cant find the specifiv name/id of the textarea of the contactform 7..

Comment: Do you mean the hook function is not executed or any syntax error? You can see the name of the textarea by inspecting using firebug.